# What are "-" and "/" means?

Tags: r

> ```
> n <- 100
> X <- matrix(rnorm(n*4), n, 4) m <- apply(X, 2, mean)
> s <- apply(X, 2, sd)
> X.1 <- t(apply(X, 1, "-", m))
> X.2 <- t(apply(X.1, 1, "/", s))
> ```

In this code, What are "-" and "/" mean??

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation for the `apply` function?

Answer (score 1):

Minus is a function of two arguments.  `apply` passes the first argument to it and the second argument to minus is m.

Thus these are all the same:

```
X.1 <- t(apply(X, 1, "-", m))

X.1a <- t(apply(X, 1, function(x) x - m))

X.1b <- t(apply(X, 1, function(x, m) x - m, m))

all.equal(X.1, X.1a, X.1b)
## [1] TRUE
```

and similarly for / .

Comment: f(x) means f(x) = x-m??

Comment: In the case of `function(x) x - m`  the variable `m` is used in the function but not defined in the function, i.e. it is a free variable, so it will traverse the chain of function environments upwards until it locates it.